# Dynamically added tr and td design issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML design:

```
<tr class="for_check">
<td>Name</td>
<td><input name="check1" class="required username" type="text" size="35"> </td>
</tr>

<tr class="for_check">
<td>Roll</td>
<td><input name="roll"  class="username" type="text" size="35"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="my_div" class="for_check">
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="for_check">
<td></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Add More" class="addmore" onClick="addInput();">&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Remove" onClick="Remove_btn();">
</td>
</tr>

<table>
```

when click Add More button then call the following javascript code.

javascript code:

```
var name = document.createElement('tr');
name.className="for_check_"+no; 
name.innerHTML = "<td>Name</td><td><input type='text' size='35'   
name='name"+no+"'    class='required username'/></td>";

var roll= document.createElement('tr');
roll.className="for_check_"+no; 
roll.innerHTML = "<td>Roll</td>
<td ><input type='text' size='35'   name='roll"+no+"' class='required username' 
id='ass"+no+"'/></td>";

$("#my_div").before(name);
$("#my_div").before(roll);
```

i,e when i click Add More button then add tr dynamically.

In Mozilla and chrome dynamically add tr and td  place  previous tr and td position that are not dynamically added.

Design in Mozilla and chrome browser:

```
Name  textbox
Roll  textbox
Name  textbox  { dynamically add}
Roll  textbox  { dynamically add }
```

But in IE8 , when click Add more button then happen the following case:

```
      Name  textbox
      Roll  textbox

Name textbox   { dynamically add}
Roll textbox   { dynamically add}
```

Dynamically added name, textbox and roll,textbox  place left position. But i need dynamically added  name, textbox and roll,textbox place previous name, textbox and roll,textbox position i,e

```
 Name  textbox
 Roll  textbox
 Name  textbox  { dynamically add}
 Roll  textbox  { dynamically add
```

Can i understand my question. Please help me.

Comment: You're not closing the `table` tag at the end. Also I'm sure you're trying your best but I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Here i do not close table but in my project i have closed table tag

Comment: Please try to reword your explanation of what is the problem, e.g. what is the problem you are having

Answer (score 0):

I believe IE requires table rows to be added explicitly to a tbody element.

Proper structure being:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```